# Select rows with a list of children rows and statuses in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table:

[image]

What I want to achieve is that when performing a select statement, I want to get the row of **id5** returned, since all of its 'children' rows has the status of **1**. The row of **id1** will not fetch because its last 'child' row has the status of **0** (i.e **id4**)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76de80

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You should use sub query to get your result.

For example:

```
select id from table where id IN (select id from table where parant_id="")
```